# Slick - Auto sliding to a new item that been added to the slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I've been testing many way on the Slick slider add & remove function.

It worked fine until I want to try to make it automatically sliding to the new item that has been added to the slideshow by pressing the Add new slide button.

```
$('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
  slideIndex++;
  $('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideIndex + '</h3></div>');
});

$('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
  $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);
  if (slideIndex !== 0){
    slideIndex--;
  }
});
```

I've tried slickGoTo but it not work out as I want so I'm totally lost here.

Comment: please create a working example of your problem. so we can help you better

Comment: Here is my codepen [link](https://codepen.io/shinva1205/pen/mweKPY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close in your codepen:

Try this:

```
$('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
  slideIndex++;
  var currentSlide = $('.slider-info').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
  $('.slider-info').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideIndex + '</h3></div>');
  $('.slider-info').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide + 1);
});
```

You need to actually get the currentSlide, in your codepen you only passed the string `'slickCurrentSlide'` and you did not call the method `slickCurrentSlide`of the slick object.

Here the working [codepen](https://codepen.io/RolandStuder/pen/KqdGjy)

Comment: so now I just need to - 1 in the delete action and everything ok, thank you very much